# How to parameterize a setup_method in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("dtype", (float32, bfloat16))
class TestA:

    def setup_method(self, method=None, dtype=float32):
        if dtype == float32:
            self.a = 10
        else
            self.a = 5

    def test1(self, dtype):
        ...
```

test1 always uses `self.a = 10`, even when the dtype is bfloat16. Does anybody know how to make it run with the correct value?

Comment: can you indent `if dtype is float32 self.a = 10 else self.a = 5` as it should ? Fow now that isnt valid python. The `:` are missing too

Comment: updated. thanks!

Comment: Did you `print(dtype)` in the code to see it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do it with [xunit style](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/xunit_setup.html) setup/teardown, it doesn't support [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture).

You can use the `pytest` setup and teardown mechanism (which is also recommended in the header of the xunit style documentation)

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("dtype", (float32, float16))
class TestA:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
    def setup_and_teardown(self, dtype):
        print('setup')
        if isinstance(dtype, float32):
            self.a = 10
        else:
            self.a = 5
        print(dtype)
        yield
        print('teardown')

    def test1(self, dtype):
        print('test1')
```

Output:

```
TestA::test1[float32] 
setup
<class 'numpy.float32'>
PASSED                            [ 50%]test1
teardown

TestA::test1[float16] 
setup
<class 'numpy.float16'>
PASSED                            [100%]test1
teardown
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works.